# Firebase, add unique id and data - promise error add/set is not a function

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

How can I add document data as well as a unique id?

I am using:

```
if (fcmToken) {
    firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .add(fcmToken)
        .set({
            year
        })
        .then(function() {
            return true;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            return false;
        });
}
```

I get the error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: _reactNativeFirebase.default.firestore(...).collection(...).add(...).set is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chaining `set` after `add` doesn't really make any sense.  The are independent operations, and both return a promise that resolves after the work is complete.  The error you're seeing is telling that the promise returned by `add` doesn't have a method called `set`.

Just use one or the other, not both.

[Using add](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#add), you can specify the entire document's content with the object you pass to it, and it will be assigned a random unique ID.

If you want to generate your own ID, build a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) to the document you want to create, and set it directly.  For example:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(fcmToken).set(...)
```

Comment: Exactly, I just noticed this! haha

Comment: I would like to set my own unique id for each doc, which is the fcm token. So I can setup a rule to not allow dupes.

Comment: Then build a reference to the known document path, and set its contents directly.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Use add instead of set. It will return the generated id.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.html?authuser=0#add